# How can I count an array element in C?

Tags: c

I make a DFA Simulator.

if Node 0 is initial state and Node 3 is final state, like weight graph implementation.

```
char CurrentStateAccept[stateN][alphabetN][alphabetN] = { {"01"} , {"0"} , {"0","1"} ,{} }; // 0, 1, 2, 3
int NextState[stateN][alphabetN] = {{1},{2},{0,3},{}};
```

I want to get 1, 1, 2, 0

- node 0, accept(0 or 1) -> node 1
- node 1, accept(0) -> node 2
- node 2, accept(0) -> node 0
- node 2, accept(1) -> node 3
- and node 3 is final state of dfa.

so I want to get char CurrentStateAccept[each state]'s element number for using 'for loop'
ex)

```
for(i=0; i<currentState element num; i++)
{
   for(j=0; j<end of alphabet of each element; j++)
   {
       there is acceptable state? or not?
   }
}
```

How can I get in C?

Answer (score 3):

you mean something like this

```
sizeof(array)/sizeof(type of array);
```

Comment: Or, even easier: `(sizeof array / sizeof array[0])`